# My favorite animal are dogs

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

My favorite animal are dogs.

Is this acceptable?

I believe this is ok because I see "animal" as one species and "dogs" as the variety of breeds.

Of course, the best answer would be "my favorite animal is the dog" but that's not the point.

Could someone give me a clear, technical answer as to whether or not this is acceptable (grammar)?

Thanks

Comment: The verb agrees with its subject, not its complement.  Dogs are your favorite animal, but your favorite animal is a dog.

Comment: *My favorite animal **is the dog.** My favorite **animals** are **dogs and cats (the dog and the cat).*** The reference in this sentence is to the **kind** of animal, not an individual.

Comment: The variety of breeds is not relevant to the context, the kind of animal alone is enough.

Comment: you might be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions.

Comment: This is a valid question that deserves an answer.

Comment: In fact, beware that the sentence actually means, whatever is your favorite animal, each one of them is a despicable create (or a very faithful friend).

Answer (score 1):

It ain't acceptable. ;)

"My favourite animal" is the subject of the sentence and singular. The verb needs to agree with the subject  in number. So it has to be "is" rather than "are": 'My favourite animal is the dog' forces the complement also agree.

Comment: Can you say, my favorite animal is a dog?